# Is it possible to get closest city to my location using nokia maps on WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, reverse-geocoding, here-api

I can get my current location on wp8. Then I am trying to do a Geocoding with nokia maps based on that location I always get odd results. None of them point to city or something like that

The code I use for getting location:

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
MyCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(position.Coordinate.Latitude, position.Coordinate.Longitude);
```

Then GeoCoding:

```
var geoQuery = new GeocodeQuery();
geoQuery.SearchTerm = "put city result of reverseGeoding for MyCoordinate";
geoQuery.QueryCompleted += geoQuery_QueryCompleted;
geoQuery.GeoCoordinate = geo;
geoQuery.QueryAsync();
```

Next:

```
void geoQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    if (e.Error == null && e.Result.Count > 0)
    {
    }
}
```

e.Result array can containg GeoCoordinates that point to somethere on earth not always close to MyCoordinate.

Is it possible to get closest city to my location using nokia maps on WP8?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ReverseGeocodeQuery` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.reversegeocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to obtain and address from geocoordinates:

```cs
ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
query.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate;
query.QueryCompleted += query_QueryCompleted;
query.QueryAsync();
```

You get an object of `MapAddress` type, which has many properties, including city:

```cs
void query_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<System.Collections.Generic.IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        return;

    MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
    string city = address.City;
}
```

In order to use this api, you have to specify `ID_CAP_MAP` capability in the *WMAppManifest.xml* file.